# How to show an element based on a selected value from a droplist with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my html :

```
<select ng-model='selectedtype' ng-options='item.tagname for item in types.name'>
    <option value="">select type</option> 
</select>
<p ng-show = 'selectedtype.tagname in {{primitives}}'> 
    <br>value of the field : <input ng-model='blockvalue' type='text' name='blockvalue'> <br>
</p>
```

I'd like to make the paragraph containing the block value input only when certain types are selected.

Here is the array containig the type :

```
$scope.primitives =["gco:CharacterString","Real","Integer","Decimal","Url","gco:Date","gco:DateTime","gco:Measure"];
```

and this is an exemple of what can be selected :

```
{
    "tagname": "gmd:abstract",
    "#text": "Abstract"
},
{
    "tagname": "gco:CharacterString",
    "#text": "Primitive type"
}
```

I know this expression can't work but i can't work a way to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since primitives is an array, you can just do this:

```
<p ng-show = 'primitives.indexOf(selectedtype.tagname) != -1'> 
    <br>value of the field : <input ng-model='blockvalue' type='text' name='blockvalue'> <br>
</p>
```

Comment: this if perfect! thank you i'll mark my question as answered asap

Answer (score 0):

Use primitives.indexOf(selectedtype.tagname) != -1 in ng-show

```
<p ng-show = 'primitives.indexOf(selectedtype.tagname) != -1'>
```